# How to send model property value to controller method in K-MVC using @Ko.Html.Button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am trying to send value of StockDate to Controller Method. I am getting Null.
http://knockoutmvc.com/ParametersToServer

as per above link if I pass static value like below.I can get value but when I use Model.Property I always get Null.

```
@ko.Html.Button("Inc 3", "Increment", "ParametersToServer", new { value = 3 })
```

Following is the code..

**View Code-**

```
    @using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model OpManWeb.ViewModel.Inventory.TransactionHistory

@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Stock";
}


<script src="~/Scripts/perpetuum.knockout.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

@using (ko.Html.Form("SaveStock", "Inventory"))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 clmargin">
                <div class="form-group  col-md-4 zeropadding div2adjustments">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StockDate, new { @class = "fieldtext" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 div2adjustments">
                    @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.StockDate, new { @class = "form-control input-sm fieldtextinput ", 
                @id="stockdatepicker" })
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

     @ko.Html.Button("Cancel", "sample1", "Inventory", new { value = Model.StockDate}, new { @class = "btn btn- primary maxheightbtn col-md-12", @id = "btn" })
}
```

**Model Code-**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace OpManWeb.ViewModel.Inventory
{
    public class TransactionHistory
    {
        [DisplayName("Stock Date")] 
        public string StockDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller Code-**

```
   public ActionResult sample1(string value)
{
    return Json(value);        
}
```

I always get null for string value in controller..
Can anyone have faced such issue..?
Help..!!
Thanks In Advance..!!

Comment: Have you tried accessing `model.StockDate` in your controller?

Comment: Yess I am getting null for string value inside my controller arguement..

Comment: That's because you aren't passing a key:value pair with the key `value` to the controller.

Comment: How can we achieve that...?Can you write answer for this question?

Comment: I know we can achieve that but i don't want to use the view model. I want to achieve this using parameter value which is passed into @ko.Html.Button..and inside controller its string value

Comment: Suppose assume that if I didn't pass View Model inside controller method in such case how can we achieve value for "string value" inside controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send back extra **static** parameters with `@ko.Html.Button`.

However you can get your whole client side model object (this is always sent by K-MVC) inside your controller action with adding a `model` parameter to it.

So you can get the current `model.StockDate` with modifying your controller action to:

```
public ActionResult sample1(TransactionHistory model)
{
    return Json(model.StockDate);        
}
```